# Jasper reports 6 & Icinga2 unable to resolve class org.icinga.reporting.DateHelper

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, icinga2

I have installed Jasper reports server 6.3.0 along with Icinga-reporting (from the git [repo](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga-reports))

I can run sample reports without any problem, but when I try and run specific Icinga reports which have a time period they fail and error out with;

`Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: calculator_Service32activity32report32in32given32time_1484836971660_629753: 13: unable to resolve class org.icinga.reporting.DateHelper @ line 13, column 1. 1 error .`

If you want the full stack trace please leave a comment and I will update the question.

I have done lots of googleing and have found afew links which reference the issue, but no one has actually said in (still valid) steps how to resolve the problem.

[This](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga-reports/issues/10) looks like the closest fit - but the info referenced no longer exists (The entire Icinga wiki has been removed!)

I also found [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/813877/unable-resolve-class-datetimefunctions-jasperreports-server) but it links to very old jars which I've included in the `WEB-INF/lib` path but still getting the same error.

If I run a report that does not have a time/date then the report works (So I know Jasper is actually working)

If you need any additional info please leave a comment & I will update the question.

Comment: Did you add lib to cp?

Comment: ? not sure what you mean - sorry

Comment: You should check that jar with `org.icinga.reporting.DateHelper` (Icinga library) is at library folder at JR Server. It should be at class path

Comment: what jar provides `org.icinga.reporting.DateHelper` that's half my problem I can't find anything specific... :(  I've updated my question with the jasper related jars that I have.

Comment: You should find this jar and add it :)  BTW, did you check this reports before uploading to the JRS?

Comment: Fixed! icinga-reporting.jar was missing..... I had copied it before but it had gone when I checked again... Ive re copied it and its working again. I'll post an answer once I get back to a pc in a couple of hrs!

Comment: Congratulations :) You can add this solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be cause by `icinga-reporting.jar` missing from the tomcat `WEB-INF/lib/` folder.

When you build `icinga-reporting.jar` it includes the `org.icinga.reporting.DateHelper` functions that where the cause of the original error.

When I installed the reporting the post deployment scripts where run and I'm sure it had copied the `.jar` file to the correct path, but when I later searched for it it was missing...

Manually copying the file to the correct path resolved the issue & reports with a time/date element now run without errors.